# How to find the sum of a count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find the count of authors for a particular year..The table is as shown below:

```
      Year                 count
    ---------           -----------
     2018                     2
     2018                     5
     2017                     4
     2017                     9
```

I want the value for 2018 as 7 (5+2) and for 2017 as 13 (9+4)
This is the sql code I wrote for count; but I am unable to find the sum 
Kindly help

```
select count(*) from author_list where year like '2018-%' group by year
```

The table defination is

```
create table author_list(name varchar(20),year varchar(20))
```

The output should be

```
      Year                 count
    ---------           -----------
     2018                     7
     2017                     13
```

Comment: just convert `group by name` to `group by year`, but how you derived the year part is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

That should be simple:

```
SELECT year, sum(count) AS count
FROM author_list
WHERE time LIKE '2015-%'
GROUP BY year;
```

If `time` is a `timestamp` column, you should use `extract(year FROM time)`.

Comment: I need the sum for each year, I am unable to use sum and count together

Comment: Sounds like you need a subquery. But unless you add the table definition to the question, I cannot tell you the SQL statement.

Comment: @JanakiRadhakrishnan This answers your original question +1.  If you have another question, then you should provide sample data for it.

Comment: The sum of count is throwing an error..I am unable to bring sum and count together

Answer (score 0):

if you want each year, you can try this one

```
SELECT year, sum(count) AS count
FROM author_list
GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: @Janaki Radhakrishnan if year have only year not timestamp or date

Answer (score 0):

If you need the name of the author and year , use the below one.

```
SELECT name ,year, sum(count) AS count
FROM author_list GROUP BY year, name;
```

If name is not required, remove name from select list and group by.